# Probability of success given binomial probability

Tags: probability

I continue with the book of Larsen and Marx: *An introduction to mathematical statistics and its applications.* There is this problem I could not solve:

A fast food chain is running a new promotion. For each purchase, a customer is given a game card that may win $10$. The company claims that the probability of a person winning at least once in five tries is 0.32 What is the probability that a customer wins $10 on his or her first purchase? The book says the answer is 0.074 but I did not reach that.

I did this: $0.32= P(\text{winning at least 1 of 5})$

$0.32 = 1-P(\text{not winning in any try})$

But then, I do not know how to continue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1 - 0.32 = P$(not winning in any try) = $P$(not winning in one try)$^5$

$P$(not winning in one try)$ = (1-0.32)^\frac{1}{5}$

$P$(winning in one try)$ = 1 - P$(not winning in one try)$ = 1-(1-0.32)^\frac{1}{5}  \approx 0.0742328151$

Comment: Great! Thanks Y. Forman!

Comment: Hi Y. Forman  ! Can you help me with my last question? It is about the pannini album. Thanks a lot!